# Function returns const ref to std::unique_ptr, can it return null?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a function that return const ref to a std::unique_ptr. I'm getting this ptr  from some container. I want to have a possibility to return nullptr or something when in my container of std::unique_ptr there is no appropriate object to the input values. It seems to be impossible with const ref. There is definitely an option to return const raw pointer, but I would like to stick to std::unique_ptr if it's possible.

Comment: Just return a raw pointer.  `unqiue_ptr` ans `shared_ptr` are to express ownership.  If the caller isn't supposed to participate in that, then a raw non-owning pointer is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an interface that returns a reference to an object, then that interface is referring to an object that exists somewhere in the program. If, in the course of trying to generate such a reference, you realize that the user has malformed their inputs or otherwise no such object exists, you have the following choices:

1. Throw an exception. This is typically how we recognize cases where the user of a function did something wrong, that they asked for a thing that didn't exist.
2. Change the function to return by value instead of by reference. In this case, it would probably be a naked pointer value, rather than a reference.

In any case, there is pretty much no reason to explicitly return an lvalue reference to a `unique_ptr` from any API. `unique_ptr` represents ownership, and if an API directly shows one, it should represent a *transfer* of ownership from the source to the destination. A function that returns an rvalue-reference to a `unique_ptr` means that it is giving the caller ownership of the object being pointed to.

If no transfer of ownership is taking place, you shouldn't be using `unique_ptr` in the API.

Note that there is a difference between a container that *knows* that it contains a `unique_ptr` and a container that *happens to* contain a `unique_ptr`. `vector<T>` is a generalized array, so the fact that `operator[]` returns a `T&` is OK even if that `T` happens to be `unique_ptr`. It is the user of the container who knows what that `T` means and how to use it.

By contrast, if your container is *conceptually* a container of `unique_ptr`s, then its API should recognize this fact.

Comment: I don't really understood the phrase " if your container is conceptually a container of unique_ptrs", can you please kindly explain?

Comment: @Bruice: A `vector<T>` is a container, but it has few requirements on what `T` must be. As such, a `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` is just a vector that *happens* to contain `unique_ptr`s. By contrast, you could imagine a type `unique_vector<T>`, where it is *specifically* a container of `unique_ptr<T>`s. You described your type specifically as "a container of `unique_ptr`". That is different from a container that could hold anything, but this particular use of it holds `unique_ptr`s.

Answer (score 2):

```
class A {
public:
    const std::unique_ptr<B>& function() {
        return m_uni;
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<B> m_uni{nullptr};
};
```

This works and the returned `unique_ptr` is nullptr. Yes it is allowed and possible. Still, returning references to `unique_ptr` is kind of a code smell. If you can share more about why you want to use `unique_ptr` and what you are using this container for, someone may be able to provide an alternative.

The modifiers on the `unique_ptr` variable itself (`const`, `&`, `*`) have nothing to do with the value stored in the `unique_ptr`.

Comment: The question says "there is no appropriate object to the input values". So `m_uni` or any equivalent does not exist.

Comment: I think you've missed a part of the question.  The OP wants to return a reference to an element in the container.  If it isn't there, then they want to return a null pointer.  Are you suggestion they keep a null pointer around to return a reference to it?

Comment: Why const references to unique_ptr is a bad practice? I have container of unique_ptr, so  it will manage objects destructions. But I don't need to give the ownership every time I need to do something with those objects, so I get const references to unique_ptr  from the container. If it's a bad practice how we supposed to use containers of unique_ptr?

Comment: Why not just allocate the objects in the container? Passing around references to `unique_ptr` pollutes your codebase with the knowledge that the object is stored in a `unique_ptr`. Why should any other code care about that? Generally code using that `unique_ptr` doesn't care that it is a `unique_ptr<T>`, they just need a `T`.

Comment: @Bruice `unique_ptr` exists to manage and document ownership. If you give your client a `const unique_ptr<T>&`, then the client has no way to take or modify that ownership, and all they can do is use the address of the pointed-to object, whether to check for `nullptr` or dereference it. Compared to returning `T*`, there is no significant difference other than that exposing `unique_ptr<T>` adds noise and could be said to leak implementation details.

Comment: @alterigel but if to return T* client can delete it. Or it can call non-cost members, and if I return const unique_ptr<T>& I'm sure object won't be changed.

Comment: @Bruice That's not true. If you return `const std::unique_ptr<T>&`, the client can still delete it (`delete ptr.get()`) and can still modify it (`ptr->nonConstFunctionOnT()`).

However, if you instead returned `const T&` then you would be correct. More reason not to return `unique_ptr` - it is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: @Bruice Dean is completely right. Also, with a raw pointer, you can return a `T const*` which can't be modified. But you can't return a `const std::unique_ptr<T const>&`.

Comment: @alterigel , DeanJohnson    I see. Thank you for helping me clarify things out! Seems like in my case only valid option is return T const*, and it also can be nullptr.